# React.js - Add button do not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  items: []
 }
}
addItem(e) {
  var itemArray = this.state.items;

itemArray.push({
  text: this._inputElement.value,
  key: Date.now()
});

this.setState({
  items: itemArray
});

e.preventDefault();
}
render() {
  return (
  <div className="main">
    <div className="header">
      <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
        <input ref={(a) => this._inputElement = a}
        placeholder="enter your message"/>
        <button type="submit">add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <todoItems entries={this.state.items}></todoItems>
  </div>
);
}
}

class todoItems extends Component {
todoEntries = this.props.entries;

createTasks(item) {
 return <li key={item.key}>{item.text}</li>
}

listItems = this.todoEntries.map(this.createTasks);

render() {
  return(
    <ul className="theList">
      {this.listItems}
    </ul>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

I try to make 'todo' app in react.js,
but it is not working add message.
it occurs refresh, and error console message :
bundle.js:30031 Warning: Unknown prop `entries` on  tag.
Remove this prop from the element.

How do I should fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React components have to start with an upper-case letter otherwise it will not be recognized as such. Should be

```
<TodoItems.../>
```

Comment: Note: If it's not uppercase, it will not be recognized as a component as mentioned above, INSTEAD it will be recognized as a regular (custom) HTML DOM element and "entries" is not a valid HTML attribute, that's why it wants you to remove it.